# Aternating columns in two files and make one file

Tags: shell, awk

I have two text files (`tsv` format), which each have 240 columns and 100 lines. I would like to sort the columns alternately and make one file (480 columns and 100 lines).　How could I achieve this goal with standard command line tools in Linux?

Example (in case of a single line) :

```
FileA:
1 2 3 4 5  ・・・

FileB:
001 002 003 004 005 ・・・

Expected Result:
1 001 2 002 3 003 ・・・
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please show us some sample Inputs and expected sample output in CODE TAGS, as this is NOT clear.

Comment: Please add samples in your POST in CODE TAGS sign  like `{}` and explain the problem properly too.

Comment: File contents are all number(inspection value) and file is tag delimited.
I always use awk ,but cannot find easy way to edit this time.

Comment: ok, still samples are not clear in your post. Try given solutions and let us know how it goes then.

Comment: Are the columns sorted by default?

Comment: Yes,columns are sorted by default.

Comment: Thank you for giving me good advice.  It worked out as you pointed out.
Thanks a lot.(I can get what I wanted any way you recommended.)

Answer (score 2):

just `awk` with "getline"

```
==> file1 <==
a b c d e f g h i j k l m
n o p q r s t u v w x y z

==> file2 <==
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26

$ awk '{split($0,f1); 
        getline < "file2"; 
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s%s%s", f1[i], OFS, $i, (i==NF?ORS:OFS)}' file1

a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8 i 9 j 10 k 11 l 12 m 13
n 14 o 15 p 16 q 17 r 18 s 19 t 20 u 21 v 22 w 23 x 24 y 25 z 26
```

if space is not the required output delimiter set `OFS` accordingly...

ps.  **getline** use is normally discouraged for any non-trivial script, and usually should be avoided by beginners.  See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline.html) for example for more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

**`paste`** + **`awk`** solution:

Sample `file1`:

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

---

Sample `file2`:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26
```

---

```
paste file1 file2 \
| awk '{ len=NF/2; 
         for (i=1; i<=len; i++) 
             printf "%s %s%s", $i, $(i+len),(i==len? ORS:OFS) 
       }'
```

The output:

```
a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8 i 9 j 10 k 11 l 12 m 13 n 14 o 15 p 16 q 17 r 18 s 19 t 20 u 21 v 22 w 23 x 24 y 25 z 26
a 1 b 2 c 3 d 4 e 5 f 6 g 7 h 8 i 9 j 10 k 11 l 12 m 13 n 14 o 15 p 16 q 17 r 18 s 19 t 20 u 21 v 22 w 23 x 24 y 25 z 26
```

Comment: Thank you for your replying. I will try it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `bash` to make some dummy files that match the spec, along with some letter-line suffixes to tell them apart:

```
for f in {A..z} {A..j} ; do echo $( seq -f     '%g'"$f" 240 ) ; done > FileA
for f in {z..A} {j..A} ; do echo $( seq -f '%03.3g'"$f" 240 ) ; done > FileB
```

Use `bash`, `paste` and `xargs`:

```
paste -d' ' <(tr ' ' '\n' < FileA)  <(tr ' ' '\n' < FileB) | xargs -L 240 echo
```

---

Since the output of that is a bit unweildy, show first ten lines, with both the first and last six columns:

```
paste -d' ' <(tr ' ' '\n' < FileA)  <(tr ' ' '\n' < FileB) | xargs -L 240 echo | 
    head | cut -d' ' -f1-6,476-480
1A 001z 2A 002z 3A 003z 238z 239A 239z 240A 240z
1B 001y 2B 002y 3B 003y 238y 239B 239y 240B 240y
1C 001x 2C 002x 3C 003x 238x 239C 239x 240C 240x
1D 001w 2D 002w 3D 003w 238w 239D 239w 240D 240w
1E 001v 2E 002v 3E 003v 238v 239E 239v 240E 240v
1F 001u 2F 002u 3F 003u 238u 239F 239u 240F 240u
1G 001t 2G 002t 3G 003t 238t 239G 239t 240G 240t
1H 001s 2H 002s 3H 003s 238s 239H 239s 240H 240s
1I 001r 2I 002r 3I 003r 238r 239I 239r 240I 240r
1J 001q 2J 002q 3J 003q 238q 239J 239q 240J 240q
```